# Force netcat to send messages immediately (without buffering)

Tags: linux, netcat

I'm using a python script to generate data using standard print() arguments. The output from the script should then be sent to localhost tcp socket 9999.

```
python script.py | nc -lk 9999
```

On the client side I'm listening to localhost tcp socket 9999 to verify everything is working fine.

```
nc localhost 9999
```

And yes, it's working. But it looks like nc is buffering some messages before sending them. As a result, I get huge delays on the client side, which is not acceptable for my application: I need the data asap.

Is there a way to disable the buffer?

I noticed that if I send more messages, the delay decreases. However, this isn't really a solution for me.

Comment: Did you do a Google search? "linux netcat no buffer" gave me this as the first result: http://superuser.com/a/429134/206562

Comment: Yes, I saw this post. However, it didn't work for me when using my script.

Comment: It's worth noting that `nc` never buffers, it always sends data immediately. It's the python program that's buffering because stdout is not a terminal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `stdbuf` command:

```
stdbuf -o0 python script.py | stdbuf -i0 nc -lk 9999
```

or the -u Unbuffered option for python:

```
python -u script.py | stdbuf -i0  nc -lk 9999
```

I/O buffering is, unless a program explicitly handles it on it's own, handled by the libc. `stdbuf` influences that behaviour. Further reading [`man stdbuf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf).