# Ubuntu: Pipe raw unbuffered data to TCP port

Tags: linux, tcp, pipe, streaming, buffering

**My overall goal:**
I have a hardware device that streams sensor data to a Ubuntu laptop running a Python script. Data comes in chunks of 240 samples (one per line with \n) every 2 seconds and prints to stdout. I start the Python script on the Ubuntu laptop and pipe its output to a TCP port using netcat. I connect to that TCP port from any other device on the network and get the live data stream - **without first loading all previous samples**.

**My Setup:**
Two laptops.

1: Ubuntu collects readings from a sensor, and pipes those readings to TCP port 1234.(This is working.) `$ py read_sensors.py | nc -lk 1234`

2: Windows 10, has WSL, Python, and existing scripts for processing data streamed from the first laptop. (This is working in WSL) `$ nc 10.10.10.01 1234`

**My Problem:**
I begin streaming sensor data on the Ubuntu laptop.
10 min later I connect to that stream from my windows laptop...

**I expect** to receive the most recent sample at the time the connection was established, and all subsequent samples in (pseudo) real-time.

**Instead**, as soon as I connect I am flooded with all samples collected since I began the streaming pipeline on the Ubuntu laptop, and once it catches up, I start seeing real-time data.

**I have tried:** Searching led me to try stdbuf. Lack of results led me to try various combinations of `$ stdbuf -oL py read_sensors.py | nc -lk 1234` `$ py read_sensors.py | stdbuf -oL nc -lk 1234` but every time I wait a little bit then connect to the port from my windows laptop, it loads all samples from the time I started streaming on the Ubuntu laptop.

**I assume:** This is a buffering issue and that it will have to be fixed on the Ubuntu machine - but the various combinations of stdbuf has not had any effect on the behavior of the system. So, I turn to the SO gods for insight and grace :)

-Nick

Comment: TCP is a streaming protocol. It is correct behaviour that you get all data since the beginning of the connection. Consider UDP.

Comment: Have you considered adding a TCP server to read_sensors.py, instead of piping to nc? That way you could read and transmit the sensor values only when the TCP client is connected. (I'm assuming you have a 1:1 use case and don't have to worry about multiple concurrent clients.)

Comment: @jamieguinan is correct. See my answer for an easy way to do that.

Comment: @jamieguinan I could do that and that would be my next step but time is limited and I was hoping this would be a simple thing to pull off just using pipes. (yeah, not worried about multiple clients)

Comment: @user207421 My understanding is that UDP is prone to continuity issues? I've tried adding -4 -u to the nc calls on both machines but nothing comes through on my windows machine.

Comment: Of course UDP doesn't have reliability, but if you only want the latest data why do you care? And how can you have reliability without it delivering all the data from the beginning of the connection?

Comment: @user207421 I tried UDP by running `$ py read_sensors.py | nc -u4 -lk 1234` on Ubuntu whihc just sits and runs (no prompt) and `$ nc -u4 10.10.10.01 1234` on WSL and it just times out with no message.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might meet the overall goal. Based on https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example

```
import socketserver

class MyHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        bytes = read_sensor_data() # call the code that reads the sensors                                
        self.request.sendall(bytes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with socketserver.TCPServer(("localhost", 1234), MyHandler) as server:
        server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: This will definitely work, and is the direction I am headed, but I was just hoping for a simple bash solution in the meantime.

Answer (score -1):

Disable netcat buffering:

[Force netcat to send messages immediately (without buffering)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204697/force-netcat-to-send-messages-immediately-without-buffering#34204861)

Alternately, I believe if you use bash’s built in tcp connections bypassing netcat, it will work.  E.g. read_sensors.py > /dev/tcp/10.10.10.1/1234

**EDIT:** Added sample code that shows how to send and receive.

**Example code:**

**To send:**

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
   date  > /dev/tcp/localhost/1234 || true # replace date command with read_sensors.py
   sleep 1
done
```

**to receive:**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ nc -lk 1234
```

**Output:**

```
Tue Mar  2 20:40:24 UTC 2021
Tue Mar  2 20:40:25 UTC 2021
Tue Mar  2 20:40:26 UTC 2021
Tue Mar  2 20:40:27 UTC 2021
^C
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ nc -lk 1234
Tue Mar  2 20:40:40 UTC 2021
Tue Mar  2 20:40:41 UTC 2021
```

Notice 13 second gap while I hit control C, no data sent or buffered up.

Comment: That won't stop TCP from buffering and delivering every byte that has ever been sent.

Comment: It's not TCP buffering it. It's netcat buffering it.  If you do echo test > /dev/tcp/localhost/1234 it drops the packets because there is nothing listening on port 1234.  The posters requested behavior was that if he doesn't start listening for 10 minutes, then the things he wasn't listening for don't get sent. This answer accomplishes that.

Comment: I tried both options mentioned in the link you provided and neither has resolved the issue.

`stdbuf -o0 ./read_sensors.py | stdbuf -i0 nc -lk 1234`
`python -u ./read_sensors.py | stdbuf -i0 nc -lk 1234`

My system does not have /dev/tcp.

I also tried `python -u ./read_sensors.py | nc -O128 -lk 1234` Setting NC's output buffer to a low value, no luck. 

hmm....

Comment: /dev/tcp is not a real device, it's a convention of bash. If you run your python script from within bash, it should be available.  The basic idea is, send the traffic across the network immediately. If nothing is listening on the other end, then the packets will get dropped immediately instead of queueing up. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I've tried it but response is:
`bash: /dev/tcp/10.10.10.10.1/1234: Connection refused`
I'm running as root.

Comment: It's saying connection refused because you have nothing listening on the other end.  Fire up netcat on 10.10.10.1:1234 to listen and you will receive messages. Take it down and the messages will get dropped with "connection refused" instead of buffering up.

Comment: (Note that I am now ssh'd into the Ubunu laptop via WSL and trying this) When I copy/paste your "to send" into a `test.sh` file and run it i just get permission denied over and over - as expected. When I open a second WSL window and ssh into the same machine/user and run `nc -lk 1234` I did get similar output  to what you showed. Although, eventually the timestamps started coming in out of order and now even when I try ^C the process on both ends and re-running the commands nothing happens. If try `$ nc 10.10.10.1 1234` directly from WSL it just times out.