# Increase netcat read buffer from 4KB to 10KB

Tags: bash, sockets, netcat

I try to use `netcat` as a quick-and-dirty socket server to receive requests with four words: `m base exponent modulus`, for example `m 119911077684 3 25`. I get back the result of the calculation.

This works OK until I send a request with a length of more than 4KB length.

My "server" script:

```
#!/bin/bash
eol=$'[^\n]*' # needed for bash regex

coproc nc -k -I 1 -l localhost 3000

while read -r input; do
  if [[ "$input" =~ ^m\ [0-9]+\ [0-9]+\ [0-9]+${eol} ]]; # m base exponent modulo
  then # modpow
    base=$(echo $input | awk {'print $2'})
    exp=$(echo $input | awk {'print $3'})
    mod=$(echo $input | awk {'print $4'})
    modPowResult=$(echo "(${base}^${exp})%${mod}" | bc | awk {'print $NF"."'})
    echo "Received modPow request for $input. Result: $modPowResult" 1>&2
    echo $modPowResult
  else
    echo $input | wc -c # if pattern does not match, echo byte length of request
  fi
done <&"${COPROC[0]}" >&"${COPROC[1]}"
kill "$COPROC_PID"
```

I start the script and send with another netcat instance the request:

```
$ echo "m 123456789 3 45" | nc -N localhost 3000
24.
```

This is correct. But when my request is much larger (see below, it is very long, ca. 10KB),  I only get `4096` as reponse, because obviously my request gets cut off after 4KB and the pattern does not match anymore.

**How can I increase the buffer size to 10KB?**

I am using `nc` from the netcat-openbsd package, version 1-206-1ubuntu1 on [Linux Mint 20.3](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/nc_openbsd.1.html)

---

The long request that I send:

`echo "m 119911077684388654464905913640776437154226670795608893126674401497793499190599280364130861725657104256566310462928507333209140730941832679850546964169574064502302506332980156346356353770204888295893093063184171997362057589517916010232980225391190320750952316465242324362891959100433858192271524147327414193082762890942035801958435316746500255772469345443216706039859433187598295446068294406788893004692563776136880999772523175303498038904595251052460892879542020390119365589551790081268294658670278839814000163620963699270901605327269182105315861334765282825877117237939020225059516048118822507748006320140239127478171838351066517019561839074929762330738028988275952662573265475737958301112851610595197531548497931446195952199321225970603280237392220002522234886604777354155305811126368542319814508734009724324574699762651933585658723268760338177467622997981508947488138668393644460194683162338182424638860784463205640320448417099383855382072818522929202040238994871533168133096831111510329881339134763052538793876982638221330371252613725855423571592146896758029880815370773533166968689127694703613734175707262846305586680102089283714672783584517247301712969997094188100846219871156880235250247262980941183982704470095357213637606107507347453851859858258698250607011513572535484062678271610484502455298006740369910804762417997008476244552290202422317383157478396506467483547744680169844974572967951447559272841442146195443163534430952926895944261405130537737083631290680916949035417377083444415613476470341303467658036432355832593865630222641297800142546121968228846670197431109658981524433553756516953169470270906175492638718257553629213095100747917452682253534211285832629838466511684445690038642779739911400231376076345271912866270126103787029556428130767593052626081831221831223069580448091335438929310705480858617960388692829148459668614553232856571359456182303111874697232026093026735470157165631651212560517025642976319831045781661538333599277034496981219269694512980275812089778730557632740797476353145760258328215998308472261145339422239050482532352129878920788865567995314629458455327155286460238383601946131961867426246265063123310726106693688718664044349515654363702741294452618335274329308578472175698617007182314284268398046497119531245936875755301603221798084316149598933360094885522867791011019273879574214058612225280983080451350767657126400778161555154304319817144617977921922780590457889389437733151154458594456669604913268357425018532675449321843724352306079286744292171948217434515478917308576498176270964164503811434926456683997368072955780726407859396433392794616507815229616209090535536963109780002140901827906975627967234293316955484216859007738529128975244401216085490915871531024507388309924318957155664906647334284585657638205005354547972419069669305452946639321947833394012435994802212916314476136632901669877608954569163544585174720274193743687733458152918021103753102103947757555536761250496423878947836539892181876319734828966403334468831996533582017308189424762055828357515602936391523294046491166211479541642683423998481465228274715001337998653123393277987627077776818291591865084393516551743127086475215375488202768688468221850610667101157756129583386649154755248232529575715947587573192188002157902017334436011038795700079402462826143560097658389200375725241631103202999992556312624592938137480846350848412026903419748096472380721662811550019522587811231052807795247261396319322540786904514244002649655444936516678315615815509490655441432557060506710854423809303803799832928358980279269976326443553767226117625378677721292146178144549137705670729846916993352305260256590882027591743518081622859024428432168499789050705296010312198688149480829077360824768339796901501769440011904610841999354713730007228733819400623210253248584255483381392135718982605469783073713176584693762824529856548255829134252116676403607113453428329546378911527121717218999162743029739470118529567736972067845106858183596445431859293814234467541362869837645245531687840718971450084815430300571277137631369480578785256511883434866398115621625953321395003577260895315118187411368327379978003552361264941991367588687121311204075732836962000799670126804000341688676901753702477021783266973371801241580953827616710188316672824198593419336050954281253130376778353822189824793800377718546601238247633120718659688831387817435649580877050448379012109503469868396520377378126968305945002734231194704115340864046955006030320932229997317614731989768411151227868361921843660344264921010915708495738985694574122911876672320122306870878930188687145058261733930157339319798025944904157368343854051187139367584319089952511053991867768078683402834031280370390040928451335081517037741108170426931092914661068970885818584596678595958636380828215961484655468488414470923291859914117819582725965617477747349015436236760229667348629664530116390566373561395785664859008004089692090065941440053939927994563495221580087238773509064814875447794256225 3 119911077684388654464905913640776437154226670795608893126674401497793499190599280364130861725657104256566310462928507333209140730941832679850546964169574064502302506332980156346356353770204888295893093063184171997362057589517916010232980225391190320750952316465242324362891959100433858192271524147327414193082762890942035801958435316746500255772469345443216706039859433187598295446068294406788893004692563776136880999772523175303498038904595251052460892879542020390119365589551790081268294658670278839814000163620963699270901605327269182105315861334765282825877117237939020225059516048118822507748006320140239127478171838351066517019561839074929762330738028988275952662573265475737958301112851610595197531548497931446195952199321225970603280237392220002522234886604777354155305811126368542319814508734009724324574699762651933585658723268760338177467622997981508947488138668393644460194683162338182424638860784463205640320448417099383855382072818522929202040238994871533168133096831111510329881339134763052538793876982638221330371252613725855423571592146896758029880815370773533166968689127694703613734175707262846305586680102089283714672783584517247301712969997094188100846219871156880235250247262980941183982704470095357213637606107507347453851859858258698250607011513572535484062678271610484502455298006740369910804762417997008476244552290202422317383157478396506467483547744680169844974572967951447559272841442146195443163534430952926895944261405130537737083631290680916949035417377083444415613476470341303467658036432355832593865630222641297800142546121968228846670197431109658981524433553756516953169470270906175492638718257553629213095100747917452682253534211285832629838466511684445690038642779739911400231376076345271912866270126103787029556428130767593052626081831221831223069580448091335438929310705480858617960388692829148459668614553232856571359456182303111874697232026093026735470157165631651212560517025642976319831045781661538333599277034496981219269694512980275812089778730557632740797476353145760258328215998308472261145339422239050482532352129878920788865567995314629458455327155286460238383601946131961867426246265063123310726106693688718664044349515654363702741294452618335274329308578472175698617007182314284268398046497119531245936875755301603221798084316149598933360094885522867791011019273879574214058612225280983080451350767657126400778161555154304319817144617977921922780590457889389437733151154458594456669604913268357425018532675449321843724352306079286744292171948217434515478917308576498176270964164503811434926456683997368072955780726407859396433392794616507815229616209090535536963109780002140901827906975627967234293316955484216859007738529128975244401216085490915871531024507388309924318957155664906647334284585657638205005354547972419069669305452946639321947833394012435994802212916314476136632901669877608954569163544585174720274193743687733458152918021103753102103947757555536761250496423878947836539892181876319734828966403334468831996533582017308189424762055828357515602936391523294046491166211479541642683423998481465228274715001337998653123393277987627077776818291591865084393516551743127086475215375488202768688468221850610667101157756129583386649154755248232529575715947587573192188002157902017334436011038795700079402462826143560097658389200375725241631103202999992556312624592938137480846350848412026903419748096472380721662811550019522587811231052807795247261396319322540786904514244002649655444936516678315615815509490655441432557060506710854423809303803799832928358980279269976326443553767226117625378677721292146178144549137705670729846916993352305260256590882027591743518081622859024428432168499789050705296010312198688149480829077360824768339796901501769440011904610841999354713730007228733819400623210253248584255483381392135718982605469783073713176584693762824529856548255829134252116676403607113453428329546378911527121717218999162743029739470118529567736972067845106858183596445431859293814234467541362869837645245531687840718971450084815430300571277137631369480578785256511883434866398115621625953321395003577260895315118187411368327379978003552361264941991367588687121311204075732836962000799670126804000341688676901753702477021783266973371801241580953827616710188316672824198593419336050954281253130376778353822189824793800377718546601238247633120718659688831387817435649580877050448379012109503469868396520377378126968305945002734231194704115340864046955006030320932229997317614731989768411151227868361921843660344264921010915708495738985694574122911876672320122306870878930188687145058261733930157339319798025944904157368343854051187139367584319089952511053991867768078683402834031280370390040928451335081517037741108170426931092914661068970885818584596678595958636380828215961484655468488414470923291859914117819582725965617477747349015436236760229667348629664530116390566373561395785664859008004089692090065941440053939927994563495221580087238773509064814875447794256225" | nc -N localhost 3000`

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quoting the variables fixed the issue.**

The solution:

```
eol=$'[^\n]*' # needed for bash regex
if [[ "$input" =~ ^m\ [0-9]+\ [0-9]+\ [0-9]+${eol} ]];
    then
      base=$(echo "$input" | awk {'print $2'})
      exp=$(echo "$input" | awk {'print $3'})
      mod=$(echo "$input" | awk {'print $4'})
      modPowResult=$(echo "(${base}^${exp})%${mod}" | (export BC_LINE_LENGTH=0; bc))
      printf "%s." "$modPowResult" # echo would work here, too
fi
```

Cyrus' [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74256156/increase-netcat-read-buffer-from-4kb-to-10kb#comment131099750_74256156) set me on track to solve the issue. I don't know enough about bash to understand it, but when quoting the `$input` throughout the script solved my issue.

The topics that came up when I searched for these kind of things (stdbuf, socat, bash/kernel buffer settings etc., also mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74256321/2422617)) where not the culprit here.

Answer (score 0):

This is the man page for netcat.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54763/netcat-1.html
The -b switch should allow you to increase your buffer size. Default is 1024, but it could be different for different distributions.
Edit: Ok, this post shows the use of stdbuf.
[Force netcat to send messages immediately (without buffering)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204697/force-netcat-to-send-messages-immediately-without-buffering)
Sorry for any misunderstanding.
Edit: There’s a command called socat which might help. Here is the man page.
https://linux.die.net/man/1/socat

Edit: It seems like the buffer is written into the source code.

```
iPhone:~/netcat-0.7.1/src# grep -Hn "4096" *
misc.c:264:  char buf[4096], *p, *rest;
iPhone:~/netcat-0.7.1/src# grep -Hn "1024" *
core.c:185:      unsigned char buf[1024];
core.c:287:     /* FIXME: this ONLY saves the first 1024 bytes! and the others? */
core.c:528:  unsigned char buf[1024];
misc.c:347:        "Example: '1-1024'\n"));
```

I guess it would be possible to edit it and use the buffer size you want, but I’m not sure if there are any caveats.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but that is nc on Solaris. In Debian/Ubuntu/Linux Mint, this parameter does not exist, -b has a different meaning there. https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/nc_openbsd.1.html. I update the question to be more specific about the nc version that I use, since there are a lot of differences across UNIXoid OSes

Comment: Thank you, my research went into the same direction. However, in this case the solution unexpectedly was more about syntax, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74260474/2422617). Thank you @Cyrus for the tip with shellcheck.